# get the parent element and find the button element and replace the text of it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this codes.

html

```
<div class="has_dropdown">
    <button>Select branch</button>
    <ul class="dropdownmenu">
        <li><a href="#">Branch 1</li>
        <li><a href="#">Branch 2</li>
        <li><a href="#">Branch 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and this jquery script

```
$('.dropdownmenu li a').click(function(){
    //go to the .has_dropdown which is the parent container and find button element within it and then replace the text of it with the current click anchor element text.
    $(this).parent('.has_dropdown').find('button').text($(this).text());
});
```

as you can see from the script code, it will go to the parent element .has_dropdown and then look for the button element inside of it and then replace the button's element text with the text of the current clicked element (.dropdownmenu li a) but sadly not working. Any help clues, ideas, suggestions, recommendations to make this work?

Comment: Change `.parent` to `.closest`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the element `.has_dropdown` isn't the direct parent of the `<a>` element. You need to use the [`.closest()` method](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/jm9tykgh/)

```
$('.dropdownmenu li a').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.has_dropdown').find('button').text($(this).text());
});
```

The [`.parent()` method](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) traverses to the immediate parent whereas the [`.closest` method](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) traverses up through its ancestors.

Answer (score 0):

`.parent()` retrieves only the closest parent element, which is `<li>` in your html. If you prefer to get to the button by just using `parent()` you can do this:

```
$('.dropdownmenu li a').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().prev().text($(this).text());
});
```